# Webpack 3 with bower

Tags: webpack, bower

I'm trying to integrate webpack 3 with bower components. However, I cannot seem to make it reads `bower.json` for the main file.

This is my configuration:

```
{
context: __dirname,
devtool: 'inline-sourcemap',
entry: entries,
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'build/js/modules/'),
  filename: '[name].bundle.js',
},
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.coffee$/,
      use: [
        { loader: 'coffee-loader' },
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.js|\.jsx$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              [
                'env',
                {
                  targets: {
                    node: '6.11.4',
                    browsers: [
                      'last 2 versions',
                      '> 5%',
                      'ie >= 11',
                      'not and_chr > 0',
                      'not and_uc > 0',
                      'not android > 0',
                      'not ie_mob > 0',
                      'not ios_saf > 0',
                      'not op_mini > 0',
                    ]
                  },
                },
              ],
              'es2015',
              'react',
            ],
            plugins: []
          }
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.jade$/,
      exclude: [/node_modules|bower_components/],
      use: [
        { loader: 'jade-loader' },
      ]
    }
  ]
},
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.coffee'],
  alias: {
    'spinner': path.resolve(__dirname, '../common/public/scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js'),
  },
  descriptionFiles: ['package.json', 'bower.json'],
  modules: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
  mainFields: ['module', 'main'],
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'common',
    minChunks: 3,
  }),
],
```

}

I don't know what I have done wrong.

I'm using `webpack: 3.6.0`
bower components are in `build/bower_components/`

Comment: I am trying to migrate from grunt+bower to webpack+bower. Don't find anything handy. Don't know what's missing.

Comment: apparently using bower with webpack is kind of discouraged. I ended up either finding the same package in npm, or fork the bower package to a private repository and use nom to fetch it.

good thing is that now we have deprecated bower completely from our project.

Comment: Hey @lightbringer do you have some notes of how you migrated. Am facing a tough time with this.

Comment: @swateek basically just replace bower packages with npm packages, and those that cannot be migrated, I ended up putting them into the source as third-party code, then use webpack to process them,

Comment: thank you @lightbringer but I still haven't gotten time to work on this. Can I connect with you somewhere to get help from later sometime, if you are okay?

Comment: sure, my linkedin is https://www.linkedin.com/in/tuan-nguyen-bab67141/